# JSON retornando dois erros diferentes PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter

Estou utilizando o PHP com Codeigniter, e está dando esse erro em um ajax que estou usando, não consigo descobrir o que é, recebo essas duas mensagens:

> syntaxerror: unexpected token < in JSON at position 1,

E esta:

> Problema ocorrido: parsererror Descrição: SyntaxError: JSON.parse:
>   unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Sempre que faço essa requisição com ajax. Meu javascript está assim:

```
  if (!erro_validacao) {
                  e.preventDefault();

                  $.ajax({
                     type: 'post',
                     url: 'http://localhost/painel/pagar/pg_boleto',
                     data: form.serialize(),
                     dataType: 'JSON',
                     beforeSend: function(){
                       $('.msg_envio_pagamento').html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Enviando dados de pagamento, aguarde...</div>');
                     },
                      success: function(res){
                        $('.msg_envio_pagamento').html('');
                         if (res.erro == 0) {

                              $('.pedido_pagamento').remove();
                              var msg_sucesso = '<div class="row margin-top-40">'+
                                                   '<div class="col-md-12 text-center">'+
                                                      '<h2>' + res.msg + '</h2>'+
                                                      '<p>Status do pedido: ' + res.status + '</p>'+
                                                      '<p>Número do pedido: ' + res.numero_pedido + '</p>'+
                                                      '<p>Código da transação: ' + res.cod + '</p>'+
                                                      '<p>Código da transação: ' + res.cod + '</p>'+
                                                      '<p>'+
                                                      '<a href="' + res.url_boleto + '" title="Imprimir Boleto" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" target="_Blank">'+
                                                       'Imprimir Boleto'+
                                                      '</a>'+
                                                      '</p>'+
                                                   '</div>'+  
                                                 '</div>';
                                      $('.pedido_pagamento').html(msg_sucesso);           

                         } else {
                             $('.msg_envio_pagamento').html('');
                             $('.erro_validacao').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+ res.msg +'</div>');
                         }
                      },
                      error: function(request, status, erro, response){
                       $('.msg_envio_pagamento').html('');
                         alert('Erro ao salvar cadastro');
                         alert("Problema ocorrido: " + status + "\nDescição: " + erro);
                       //Abaixo está listando os header do conteudo que você requisitou, só para confirmar se você setou os header e dataType corretos
                       alert("Informações da requisição: \n" + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
                       console.log('response:', response);
                      }
                  });
              } else {
                  $('.msg_envio_pagamento').html('');
                  $('.erro_validacao').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+ retorno_erro_validacao +'</div>');
              }
       });
    }
```

E no meu alert request:

```
alert("Informações da requisição: \n" + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
```

Ele retorna a resposta:

```
Informações da requisição: 
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
connection: Keep-Alive
content-length: 605
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 29 Mar 2020 01:12:11 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
keep-alive: timeout=5, max=100
pragma: no-cache
server: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.1
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.1
```

Não sei mais como resolver, e o porque de estar retornando isso, sendo que na tabela do banco de dados, ele chega a gravar os dados, mas na pagina ele retorna isso.

Comment: Esse fragmento não esta relacionado ao erro informado. O erro está sendo gerado em uma chamada ao método `JSON.parse()` que nesse fragmento não aparece.

Comment: Sua requisição está retornando `content-type: text/html`, deveria retornar `content-type: application/json`. Talvez o erro não seja somente isso, mas certamente isso está errado.

Comment: Mds e como eu vejo esse erro? ou mudo pra application/json? eu sou iniciante e comprei um cursinho pra aprender mais, dai está aparecendo esses erros que ta me deixando louco já, se puderem me ajudar agradeço

Comment: Dá um ctrl+f , ou equivalente, na seu fonte para localizar as chamadas ao método `JSON.parse()`. Com certeza uma das chamadas e a problemática, então associe um break point a cada chamada para que possa inspecionar os dados passado para o método.

Comment: Tentei fazer, coloquei um break point, e agora ele me retorna apenas esse erro:  'Problema ocorrido: parsererror. Descrição: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data'

Comment: To achando que pode ser algum erro na função que estou fazendo. Algum caracter a mais que está sendo inserido.

Comment: Bom depois de tanto pesquisar, parece que o erro está vindo da API do pagseguro que estou tentando utilizar, infelizmente ainda não sei pq, mas vou tentar descobrir e coloco aqui

Comment: @Ragnar, nesse breakpoint inspecione o valor do string `data` antes de ser analisado por `JSON.parse()` passe-o por um validador JSON. PS: coloque um `@` antes do nome do usuário que você quer direcionar o comentário senão o sistema não informa sobre a comunicação.

Comment: @Augusto Vasques, obrigado pelas dicas irmão, pelo que eu consegui descobri o problema é na minha função, ele ta passando o array vazio, por isso ele não identifica os dados, vou ter que pedir ajuda em outro forum, pq minha cabeça já ta fervendo kkkk mto obrigado pela ajuda. valew